# Unable to remove null from observable array

Tags: rxjs, rxjs7

Even though I've defined a type guard filter, I can't seem to get rid of my `null` observables.  I defined my type guard:

```js
export const hasValue = <T>(value: T): value is NonNullable<T> => value !== null && value !== undefined
```

and then my methods that want to filter like so:

```js
#validateDocument(document: IDocument): Observable<AcmsDocumentBad | null> { ... }

validateDocuments(documents: IDocument[]): Observable<AcmsDocumentBad[]> {
    const observables = documents
        .filter(x => x.approvedSor === 'ACMS')
        .map(this.#validateDocument)

    return forkJoin(observables)
        .pipe(filter(hasValue))
}
```

I had expected that uses the pipe like that would result in `Observable<AcmsDocumentBad[]>` as the type, but it's still showing as `Observable<(AcmsDocumentBad | null)[]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forkJoin(Array<Observable<AcmsDocumentBad | null>>)` returns an `Observable<Array<AcmsDocumentBad | null>>`, which emits an array with all the results just once, when all of the inner observables have completed.

If you do `.pipe(filter(hasValue))` on this, the result will be the same, because the observable never emits nulls, it will emit just one Array, guaranteed. The inner values of that array could be null though.

You probably want to just do `.pipe(map(array => array.filter(hasValue)))`

Or if you don't fancy array methods, `.pipe(switchAll(), filter(hasValue), toArray())` (i.e. flattening the `Observable<Array<T>>` to `Observable<T>`, filtering, then recreating the array with the values filtered.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you for explaining.